# GUI, java, SWT and world map representation

Tags: java, swt

I'm trying to implement a small-scale strategy, taking turns game
implemented in Java, GUI is made with JFace and SWT.

My challenge is to write a GUI implementation of the world map, 
where countries will act as clickable buttons. However, countries
have no fixed boundaries, no rectangular shape, and simply no way
I can think of to be described in a grid layout.

This is my first time trying to implement a project of this type,
please advise

Answer (score 3):

If it's a tile based map (like at Civilization) or it's displayed as pixmap, you could save the ownership of each tile/pixel in a two-dimensional array. Just display the map a a simple, clickable pixmap in a canvas an add a MouseListener. If you get a click event at the coordinates (X,Y), you can just get your country like:

```
Country clickedCountry = myCountriesOnMap[X][Y];
```

... in your Listener implementing the MouseListener interface. myCountriesOnMap would be of type Country[][].

Of course, you will need an algorithm that will resolve the ownership for each tile/pixel at startup or if a territory gets conquered (I don't know, if this may happen). May be you  will have to define your countries as polygons (like you would do it for a HTML map). I cannot help you on this, as I haven't done anything similar jet, but I'm sure you will find something on Google.

Greetings

Sacher

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org) data. It contains exact country borders and good image export possibilities.

The [Key:border tag](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:boundary) will show you all borders. You could extract it and calculate your clickable areas.